# Will my program be faster if I overwrite a file or if I make a new one and then delete them both?

Tags: java, performance, pointers, memory

I have a java program I wrote that writes to a file. I want to know if the program will execute faster if the program overwrites the file when it is changed (i.e. I use the same file name and just change contents). The pro I see to this is I will only have to delete one file reference. However, if I make a temporary file I don't overwrite anything; however then I have to delete two reference. 
Is there even a difference in execution time?

Comment: how big are the files?

Comment: They range from 300 - 500 kb

Comment: I do not think that this is going to be the bottleneck of you program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwriting an existing file used to be considerably faster than creating a new one in the good old days, as it saved considerably on directory operations; however even then it wasn't used much because you wanted to preserve the old file until the new file was completely written, in case of a partial failure.

Deleting an extra 'pointer', by which I assume you really mean 'file', isn't any kind of a major consideration, although it seems to me that if you overwrite you don't have to delete anything, and if you write a new file you have to do one delete and one rename.